# CL Editor in Java

Tags: text, text-editor

Trying to code a basic text editor to play around with Java's file objects and classes.
What I cannot seem to figure out is how to go about developing something like the 'nano' interface. Or 'vim' interface, for that matter.

File creation is not a problem, its editing on the fly, and post-creation editing, that has just got me.

Any ideas?

Edits: Similar questions on Stackoverflow that I found interesting:
1 [Text editor theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169440/text-editor-theory)

Comment: I've wondered how good text editors are implemented for years: what datastructures do they use to support fast insertion, deletion, writing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **CHARVA**

You can get the output like below.

Check out this link http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html

[image]

Comment: That seems great Muneer! I wanted to do something small by my self though, any idea what logic/algo that code uses?

Comment: Programmers familiar with AWT and Swing will find programming CHARVA straightforward. User interfaces can be designed on a WYSIWYG IDE, and then easily converted to CHARVA merely by changing the "import" statements to import the "charva.awt and "charvax.swing" packages instead of the standard "java.awt" and "javax.swing" packages. ---pitman.co.za

Comment: Charva is the best solution available so far. It saved me lot of work by doing apps nicely in Swing with a GUI Builder, than finally using IDE "migration scripts" to convert to the equivalent Charva classes.